# ng-table> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ngtable

I'm always getting the error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined" when trying to use ng-tables to open a page. I have a controller

**movies.js**

```
    app.controller('moviesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', 'blockUI', 'notifyService', 'lib', '$filter', 'NgTableParams', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, blockUI, notifyService, lib, $filter, NgTableParams) {
        var createTable = function (options, dataFunction) {
            return new NgTableParams(options, {
                total: dataFunction().length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(dataFunction(), params.orderBy()) : dataFunction();
                    orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) : orderedData;
                    params.total(orderedData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
        };


        var movies = [];
        $scope.moviesTable = createTable({
            page: 1, count: 10, sorting: {
                title: 'asc'
            }
        }, function () {
            return movies;
        });

            var init = function () {
                loadMovies();
            };


    var loadMovies = function () {
        blockUI.start();
        $http.get('/Api/Movies').then(
            function (response) {
            blockUI.stop();
            movies = response.data;
            $scope.moviesTable.reload();
        }, lib.handleError);
    };
    init();
}]);
```

and its html looks like that:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using System.Web.Optimization

@{
            ViewBag.Title = "Movies";

}
@section libs {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/movies")

}

<html>
<head>




</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="moviesController" block-ui="moviesContentDiv">
    <h2>Movies</h2>
    <div ng-show="movies.length < 1">
        <p>There are no registered Movies yet.</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="moviesTable.data.length < 1">

        <table ng-table="moviesTable" class="table" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="movie in $data">
                <td title="'Title'" filter="{ title: 'text'}" sortable="'title'">
                    <a ng-href="/Movie/Details/{{movie.id}}"> {{movie.title }}</a>
                </td>
                <td title="'Rank'" filter="{ rank: 'number'}" sortable="'rank'">
                    {{movie.rank}}
                </td>
                <td title="'Year'" filter="{ year: 'number'}" sortable="'year'">
                    {{movie.year}}
                </td>
                <td title="'Genre'" sortable="'genre'">
                    {{movie.genre}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="top-space-lg">
        <a href="/Movie/Create" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add movie</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html has a shared layout that part of its code has the

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/uiBootstrap")
```

on another file, I include the bundles like:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/angular-block-ui.css", "~/Content/pnotify.css"
            , "~/Content/ng-table.css", "~/Content/Site.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include("~/Scripts/angular.js", "~/Scripts/angular-route.js", 
                "~/Scripts/angular-block-ui.js", "~/Scripts/pnotify.js", "~/Scripts/directives.js","~/Scripts/ng-table.js"));
```

I'm still very new to AngularJS, HTML and C#. What can be possibly wrong and causing that error? I found nothing that could solve my problem

Comment: I presume the error is coming from here: var orderedData = params.sorting() - the question is, is 'sorting' a method on params, or a property? Also don't see an ng-app anywhere in the template, but I presume it's there?

Comment: @rrd ng-app is in the shared layout. as for sorting, I don't now much as I'm following a tutorial about it and I just copied and pasted that part. but here I have a link http://ng-table.com/#/sorting/demo-sorting-basic and another http://tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-table-sorting-with-ng-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. I had installed with NuGet the ngTable 3.0.1. After I uninstalled it and installed again but with the version 0.8.3, the error stopped and the application started to work properly.